# Not able to put assertion to validate the values of a for loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I've used for loop scanning values of a dropdown. Below is my code & it's output:

**Code:**

```
FilterDropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='postFilter']")
ListedOptions = Select(FilterDropdown)
for values in ListedOptions.options:
    print(values.text, end=' ')
```

**Output**
All Core Legacy Assets Karma

Now I want to put an assertion to validate the values in the output but when I'm trying to put assertion, syntax error is thrown. Below is my code & error output:

**Code**

```
FilterDropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='postFilter']")
ListedOptions = Select(FilterDropdown)
for values in ListedOptions.options:
    assert values.text, end=' ' == "All Core Legacy Assets Karma"
```

**Error output**

```
File "C:\Users\deepa\PycharmProjects1\MSLPythonTests\SeleniumTests\PostView-CommentOnThePost.py", line 22
    assert values.text, end=' ' == "All Core Legacy Assets Karma"
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Screenshot is attached below for reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLYyI.png)

I'm trying to validate values of the output of the for loop using assert and expecting no error.

Comment: I found a way to do the expected. Create a empty list, then append values of the for loop output in the list and then put assertion to the list. This works for me.

Comment: `end` is `print()` function parameter. The assertion should be `assert values.text == "All Core Legacy Assets Karma"`